# Using seaborn kdeplot by group. The equivalent of df.hist(by=‘col1’ ,column=‘col2’)

Tags: python, seaborn, kdeplot

trying to plot density with kdeplot. However, I can not get it to work exactly how I would like.

data = customers
groupby gender

if I code

````
customers.hist(by ='gender', column='total_trans_ct', figsize = [10,6]);```
````

I get a histogram divided for M and F clients in the dataset. However, I want a density plot so I created

```
sns.kdeplot(data=customers, x="total_trans_ct", hue="attrition_flag", fill=True, common_norm=False, alpha=0.4);
```

Which gives me the plot that I want. However, I can't figure out how to divide it into F and M. can anyone please hint how to continue?

I tried the follwing and did not work either

```
plot = sns.PairGrid(customers['gender'],hue="attrition_flag")
plot = plot.map(sns.kdeplot(data=customers, x="total_trans_ct", fill=True, common_norm=False, alpha=0.4))
```

when using  **kwargs returns error, kwargs not defined

Comment: The correct way to do this is with `g = sns.displot(kind='kde', data=customers, x='total_trans_ct', col='gender', hue="attrition_flag", height=10, aspect=1, fill=True, common_norm=False, alpha=0.4)`

Comment: Thank you!! I thought I had done something like that but not sure how it didn't work. I fixed it!

Answer (score -1):

I got it! I was really close. If anyone needs a code like this

plot = sns.FacetGrid(customers, col='gender', hue="attrition_flag", height=10, aspect=1)
plot = plot.map(sns.kdeplot,"total_trans_ct", fill=True, common_norm=False, alpha=0.4)